# remove "-" of the file names in emacs dired mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to remove "-" of the file names in editable dired mode 
below is the text

> - -rw-r--r--+ 1 dayua mkpasswd    663 Nov 14 18:11 Add-Binary.py
> - -rwxr-xr-x+ 1 dayua mkpasswd    799 Nov 14 18:11 add-two-link-list.py
> - -rw-r--r--+ 1 dayua mkpasswd    571 Nov 14 18:11 Anagrams.py
> - -rwxr-xr-x+ 1 dayua mkpasswd   1041 Nov 14 18:11 Balanced-Binary-Tree.py
> - -rwxr-xr-x+ 1 dayua mkpasswd   1241 Nov 14 18:11 Best-profit-III.aux.py
> - -rwxr-xr-x+ 1 dayua mkpasswd    830 Nov 14 18:11 Best-Time-to-Buy-and-Sell-Stock-II.py
> - -rwxr-xr-x+ 1 dayua mkpasswd   1605 Nov 14 18:11 Best-Time-to-Buy-and-Sell-Stock-III.py
> - -rw-r--r--+ 1 dayua mkpasswd   5323 Nov 20 14:48 Binary-Search-Best-Practice.py

please give some suggestions.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to change the file names of the files in the file system, or do you simply want to view the files without the "-" sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: after entering dired editable mode (aka `wdired`) go to the beginning of the buffer and do <kbd>M-% - RET RET !</kbd>

M-% is the shortcut for `query-replace`; it will prompt what you want to be replaced (`-`) and by what (empty string), then it will put you in interactive mode, where key `!` tell it to replace all occurrences.

wdired will deal properly (innore when replacing) the "-" characters at the permissions part for the dired listing.

Comment: thank you so much. I have a more complicate case. if I have pure text above, i just want to remove for the rightmost filename, not include the left attributes, what should i do?

Comment: I am not sure what the "rightmost filename" and the "left attributes" would be in your example.

Comment: "-rw-r--r--+ 1 dayua mkpasswd 663 Nov 14 18:11 Add-Binary.py" just remove "-" from "Add-Binary.py", not include text "-rw-r--r--+"

Comment: Emcas should leave out of the replace that text if you are using wdired mode

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct, especially if this will only be a one-time update, is to record a keyboard macro.

```
C-x (                        ; to begin macro
C-e                          ; to end of line
M-<space>                    ; mark beginning of region
C-r :                        ; search backward to time delimiter (:)
M-x replace-string - <blank> ; replace - with nothing
C-a                          ; beginning of line
C-n                          ; next line
C-x )                        ; end macro
```

Then it's merely a matter of repeating the macro until completed

```
C-x e
```

If you have a lot of lines, you can prefix the macro call with the number of times to repeat (50 in this example)

```
<ESC> 50 C-x e
```

I'd be very interested in learning of any regex solutions to this problem!